Multi Host Mongo replication not working with docker-compose file ( without docker swarm)
I have a corporate organization network ( let's say "ORGBD" network ).
There are 3 host PC with 101.101.10.163, 101.101.10.199, 101.101.10.138 under this "ORGBD" network.
    --- host 1 ( 101.101.10.163 )

ORGBD   --- host 2 ( 101.101.10.199 )
    --- host 3 ( 101.101.10.138 )

there are 3 docker-compose.yaml file in 3 different PC.
docker-compose.yaml in Host PC 1:
version: '3.3'
services:
  mongo1:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    container_name: mongo1
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-rs0-1/data1:/data/db
    command: --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 128

volumes:
  ./mongo-rs0-1/data1:

docker-compose.yaml in Host PC 2:
version: '3.3'
services:
  mongo2:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    container_name: mongo2
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - data2:/data/db
    command: --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 128

volumes:
  data2:


docker-compose.yaml in Host PC 3:
version: '3.3'
services:
  mongo3:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    container_name: mongo3
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - data3:/data/db
    command: --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 128

volumes:
  data3:

After running docker-compose up in every host PC it runs successfully. But when i initiate in host PC 1 it also says [ ok : 1 ] okay.
  rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "rs0",
    members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "mongo1:27017" },
      { _id: 1, host: '101.101.10.199:27017' },
      { _id: 2, host: '101.101.10.138:27017' }
    ]
  }
  )

But mongo status for host PC 2 and 3 will not show secondary state.
It shows "stateStr" : "STARTUP"
I tried mongo replication with different host PC( 1,2,3) with docker compose file. I want to do it without docker swarm.
